# Java editor in Eclipse STS sometimes has jittery lines

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I drink a lot of coffee. But I don't spill on the keyboard. And I don't type this fast. And yet, sometimes my STS Eclipse 4.14 *sometimes* does this when I'm scrolling through a file of several hundred lines:

[image]

This is in a Maven-based project of about 350 Java files across implementation and test classes, running on a Dell Inc. XPS 13 9310 (11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz × 8) laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with GNOME 42.5 and Wayland windowing:

About Eclipse STS:

```
Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.14.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 202204250734

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2022 VMware, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit https://spring.io/tools

This product includes software developed by the
Eclipse Foundation https://www.eclipse.org

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation https://www.apache.org

Lombok v1.18.24 "Envious Ferret" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/
```

Obviously not a programming question but this audience is likely the only folks who **might** have seen this...anyone?

When in this wacky state, pressing keys with no editor buffer impact (e.g. shift keys, arrow keys) does nothing to change behavior but pressing a key with editor buffer impact (e.g., space bar, letters, backspace, etc.) stops the wacky behavior. So this behavior makes me lean toward a software problem instead of keyboard hardware issue.

FWIW, I don't see this wacky behavior in my desktop environment running openSUSE 15.4.

**Update**: Similar behavior in STS Eclipse 4.17:

```
Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.17.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 202212060857
Revision: e5d4f36a56c66862556fb938ade6c05abce57d39

Copyright (c) 2007 - 2022 VMware, Inc.
All rights reserved. Visit https://spring.io/tools

This product includes software developed by the
Eclipse Foundation https://www.eclipse.org

This product includes software developed by the
Apache Software Foundation https://www.apache.org

Lombok v1.18.24 "Envious Ferret" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/
```

**Update 2**: Similar behavior in Eclipse IDE 2022-12:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)
Build id: 20221201-1913
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2022.  All rights reserved. Eclipse and the Eclipse logo are trademarks of the Eclipse Foundation, Inc., https://www.eclipse.org/. The Eclipse logo cannot be altered without Eclipses permission. Eclipse logos are provided for use under the Eclipse logo and trademark guidelines, https://www.eclipse.org/logotm/. Oracle and Java are trademarks or registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

This product includes software developed by other open source projects including the Apache Software Foundation, https://www.apache.org/.

Lombok v1.18.24 "Envious Ferret" is installed. https://projectlombok.org/
```

**Update 3**: Similar behavior in Eclipse SDK without Lombok:

```
Eclipse SDK
Version: 2022-12 (4.26)
Build id: I20221123-1800
OS: Linux, v.5.14.0-1052-oem, x86_64 / gtk 3.24.33, WebKit 2.38.2
Java vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java runtime version: 19+36-2238
Java version: 19
```

Comment: I have not seen it, but have read about an Eclipse bug that might be this and that have been fixed. STS 4.14.1 is three releases behind. So if, as you say, you're looking for someone who has seen this, look in the bug tracker.

Comment: Same behavior in 4.17, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce this with the Eclipse platform (I find nothing [here](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=line+number+org%3Aeclipse-platform&o=desc&type=issues))

Comment: Reproduced similar behavior with plain Eclipse -- see update 2.

Comment: Is it reproducible in the [Eclipse SDK](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.26-202211231800/#EclipseSDK) without Lombok?

Comment: Eclipse SDK without Lombok is also affected.